# Spring Jpa Custom Query for Filtering on List-Property

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository

I have one entity called Item. Each Item contains a number of tags. Now I want to search within tags, and get a list of applications having the same tag oder combined set of tags.

The query annotation is only for "String tag;" but not "List tags;". For example i want match tags (game, thriller) or (education, 12+).

I don't have a clue, because I use @Entity. With sql tables only, i could use a table __item_tags (fid_item, fid_tag) and only say "select * where fid_tag = 'game' OR fid_tag = 'thriller'). But even here i don't know how to express this within @Query Annotation..

```
@Entity
class Item implements Serializable
{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        List<String> tags;
}

public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Serializable>{

    Item findById(long id);

    @Query("SELECT a FROM Item a WHERE LOWER(a.Tag) = LOWER(:tag)")
    List<Item > findByTag(@Param("tag") String tag);
}
```

Comment: Don't express it with a `@Query` as that would be impossible imho (I don't think it takes a map as argument). You can extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor` and create a `Specification` which creates that part of the query for you.

Comment: How "List<String> tags" is stored in your database?